# Need help with modding HackRF One RTL-SDR card with right amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sdr

I'm trying to modding HackRF One RTL-SDR card, regarding this [RF amplifier can be damaged](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/hackrf/issues/974?fbclid=IwAR3Z0VYE-CkDCkC5NbaDa9bUb6QFN828QwZ440JtpAaGGz18IOOar8VPog8) the card has problems with TX below 100 MHz, lots of users complain about burning the MGA-81563 chip on board, and I have already burned one MGA-81563, and replaced two of them. Someone suggest LVA-123+, but pins construction are not the same. I find by myself UPC8181TB-E3-A, and don't have issue that have TX limit up to 4 GHz.

Can someone help me and choose right chip (can someone confirm that UPC8181TB-E3-A is alright), so that I can change it without burning something else in circuit? Requirement is TX from 0-500 MHz, similar voltage, same pinout.
[HackRF schematic](https://github.com/rad1o/hardware/blob/master/datasheets/else/hackrf-one-schematic.pdf) and
[How to fix a broken HackRF](https://www.onesdr.com/2020/04/09/how-to-fix-a-broken-hackrf/)
I was using Digi-Key site for comparing amplifiers.

Comment: a hackrf is not an RTL-SDR. These are simply fundamentally different devices. What are you *actually* referring to?

Comment: and: do you *actually* have the problem described in the post, i.e. operating a highly sensitive receiver with sufficiently limited input power, but with unshielded exterior next to a really high-powered transmitter with no option to improve shielding?

Comment: Yes, I already replaced once MGA-81563. Actually nobody can't tell for sure why MGA-81563 burned, from GitHub can suspect that reason is because I also transmit bellow 100MHz, and MGA-81563 datasheets min tx value is 100MHz. I find alternative, but don't know if it's going to work inside circuits.

Comment: no, that's not the reason: 100 MHz is the lowest frequency at which it still works well, it doesn't get damaged below.

Comment: So what would be reason, from yours opinion

Comment: See my comment above, where I answered exactly that.